# Could not find or load main class while passing class a argument spring batch job

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-job-monitoring

```java
public class demoRunner extends CommandLineJobRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // initialize fileappender here
        String logFile = args[args.length - 1].split("=")[1];
        DemoAppender.initializeAppender(logFile);
        CommandLineJobRunner.main(args);
    }
}
```

**Run As VM argument** : `META-INF/spring/student.xml student`

student is a job

**Location of demoRunner.java**: `demoBatchJob\src\main\java\com\ncs\sma\runner\demoRunner.java`

**Location of stduent.xml**: `demoBatchJob\src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\student.xml`

### Exception:

Error: Could not find or load main class META-INF.spring.student.xml
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: META-INF.spring.student.xml

Comment: How are you packaging and running your app? It seems that your app is looking for a class `META-INF.spring.student.xml` which means the way you are launching your app is incorrect. Please share the command you use to run your app to be able to help you.

Comment: I have use eclipse to run project by using Run configuration

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it outside `META-INF` and add the below VM argument -

`spring/student.xml`

Comment: Still it is not working getting same exception

Answer (score 0):

> Run As VM argument : META-INF/spring/student.xml student

You need to select `demoRunner` as the main class to run and pass the input file and job name `META-INF/spring/student.xml student` as "Program argument" and *not* as "VM argument".